# Is it Possible to create a Online blender-made game without python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, logic-bricks

The reason I asked is That I do not really know python, So Do I have to use python? Or am I more likely to Try to create it without python?

Comment: Have a look at [blend4web](https://www.blend4web.com) and [verge3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is almost possible. You can build the entire game using only logical blocks, but to leave the game online you will have to use a python model file to get internet connections in your game. That is another matter. Just search on youtube on this.

Comment: Ok, So i do have to use logic bricks on the Game, But not on when the player goes online?

Comment: No. You can create your game with logic bricks without problem. Now, for your game to work online, you will have to add python addon that creates the server. You understand, it's a python addon that will leave your game online. Here's a little bit about it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wu4K1NS0aBE is in Portuguese but to understand a little.

Comment: ok, I understand, so in order to create the online game, you need to install this BGE addon.

Comment: Sorry to ask you too many questions.

Comment: Nevermind about the link, I think I got it,

Comment: Do not worry, you can ask at will: D

Comment: Just to let you know that I now have created another question about MIDI, If you do not know how to do it, That's ok. I'll look for somebody else to help me, And you don't HAVE to answer it.

Comment: Here is the link: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44573/how-do-i-download-the-3ds-midi

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create Blender Game Engine games without coding!

There is working add-on called `Easy Online` for BGE, UPBGE 0.2x, and UPBGE 0.3x.

**Download for BGE / UPBGE 0.2x**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2SsDz7a95Y

**Download for UPBGE 0.3x**

https://github.com/lordloki/EasyOnline

**Tutorials**

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCledfkxccjcdVCaILs0uj7w